# Querying Turtle data through SPARQL

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune

I have uploaded my turtle files  data from AWS S3 to Neptune service.

Now I am querying below sparql from RDF4J console to view my data in Neptune  but getting "no gremlin script supplied" error.

```
neptune> select ?p ?o { <http://www.1234.com/XXX/App_Inst/1007259> ?p ?o }
select ?p ?o { <http://www.1234.com/XXX/App_Inst/1007259> ?p ?o }
Evaluating SPARQL query...
Query evaluation error: {"requestId":"62b298f5-032e-0d8e-82ac-ed88a1469298","code":"MissingParameterException","detailedMessage":"no gremlin script supplied"}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

I have configured RDF4J console as per the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql-rdf4j-console.html/) provided by AWS.

If I executing the same query from Unix EC2 instance , getting below results.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-10-69 ~]$ curl -X POST  --data-binary 'query=select ?p ?o { <http://www.1234.com/XXX/App_Inst/1007259> ?p ?o }'  http://neputne.amazonaws.com:882/sparql
```

**EDIT :**

This is the result coming from EC2 instance when ran sparql.

```
{ "head" : { "vars" : [ "p", "o" ] }, "results" : { "bindings" : [ ] }
```

Comment: This is the result coming from EC2 instance when ran sparql .{
  "head" : {
    "vars" : [ "p", "o" ]
  },
  "results" : {
    "bindings" : [ ]
  }

Comment: For me this looks like the returned result is just empty

Comment: But I have loaded my turtle data into neptune and got success message.

Comment: Well, I never used Neptune, I just said what I see from the JSON result.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like your RDF4J Console is hitting the wrong endpoint, hitting the [Gremlin server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin.html) instead of the SPARQL endpoint.

I noticed in the AWS RDF4J documentation you mention that the endpoint url they give in the examples wraps around awkwardly. Please doublecheck that the SPARQL endpoint URL you used in the Console is:

```
http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/sparql
```

and not

```
http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182
```

Comment: Thank you @ Jeen , I have modified my repository and able to execute the queries in the RDF4J console , but not getting the any results it just showing zero records, even though loaded turtle files into Neptune

Comment: I have used below curl to load the data

Comment: This sounds like a different problem than the gremlin script error. If you're seeing zero results, it just means your query doesn't match anything in the triplestore. This seems consistent with what you're seeing when you use `curl` to execute the query directly on the EC2 instance. So that means either your data is not properly loaded, or your query is incorrect. Since I don't know what your data looks like, I can't pinpoint which of these is the problem. As a tip, try a very simple query, like `select * where { ?s ?p ?o } limit 10` and see what comes back.

Comment: I have ran above sample query and showing output is zero results

Comment: @SrinivasRao right so that most likely means that there is no data in your store. Presumably something went wrong with your data upload.

Comment: Hi Jeen, I have ran curl command to upload the data and checked the loaded status . from the loader id status showing results like feed count " LOAD COMPLETED" and overall status values like status " completed" , totalrecords : 0 , totalduplicate : 0 , ................, I am  not sure why it is not picking any turtle records from turtle files which are placed in S3 .

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question about this, since it's not really related to the gremlin endpoint issue.

Comment: Any one faced this type issue " turtle records load into Neptune from S3 " . My  curl job getting succeeded  but loading zero records from s3 to Neptune , even though  turtle file have lot of records

Comment: Thank you Jeen ! , will post another question for the same

Comment: Looks like something went wrong in your bulk load request. If you have not figured this out yet, please open a support case with Neptune.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing no results, then it definitely means that your data loading had some issues. Do a detailed load status[1] using the `details` query argument and see if you can figure out what happened with your bulk load request. If you are still not able to debug it, I would recommend opening a support case with Neptune to get more information.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-status.html